# how to check if the elements of an array from an array of arrays is included in another array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i created this function `includesArray`,
it works only when like it's a direct win ([image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6AmE.png) and [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HmsN.png) is the log of its moves),
but when it's a case like [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wmKQ.png) ([image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYKB.png) is the log of its moves), it fails.
what could i do to fix it?

```js
//win moves
const winMoves = [
  //horizontally
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', '6'],
  ['7', '8', '9'],

  //vertically
  ['1', '4', '7'],
  ['2', '5', '8'],
  ['3', '6', '9'],

  //diagonally
  ['1', '5', '9'],
  ['3', '5', '7']
];

//includes array function
function includesArray(data, arr) {
  return data.some(e => Array.isArray(e) && e.every((o, i) => Object.is(arr[i], o)));
};

//turns
switch (turn) {

  //player
  case player:

    //switch the turn and add the player move
    turn = opponent;
    player.moves.push(m.customId);
    console.log(`${player.player.displayName}: ${player.moves}`);

    //check if the player won
    if (includesArray(winMoves, player.moves)) {/*...*/};

    break;

  //opponent
  case opponent:

    //switch the turn and add the player move
    turn = player;
    opponent.moves.push(m.customId);
    console.log(`${opponent.player.displayName}: ${opponent.moves}`);

    //check if the player won
    if (includesArray(winMoves, opponent.moves)) {/*...*/};

    break;

};
```

i tried the above code,
i want it to check if the elements of player.moves or opponent.moves (array) is included in winMoves (array of arrays)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3x3 grid to store the value on each spot, then check each row, column, and diagonal.

```js
let grid = [...Array(3)].map(x => Array(3).fill());
grid[0][0] = 'X';
grid[0][1] = 'X';
grid[0][2] = 'X';
function getWinner(grid) {
  // check rows
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let win = true;
    for (let j = 0; j < 3 && win; j++) 
        win = grid[i][j] === grid[i][0];
    if (win) return grid[i][0];
  }
  // check columns
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let win = true;
    for (let j = 0; j < 3 && win; j++)
        win = grid[j][i] === grid[0][i];
    if (win) return grid[0][i];
  }
  // check main diagonal
  let win = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3 && win; i++) win = grid[i][i] === grid[0][0];
  if (win) return grid[0][0];
  // check minor diagonal
  win = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3 && win; i++) win = grid[i][2 - i] === grid[0][2];
  if (win) return grid[0][2];
}
console.log(getWinner(grid));
```